# How to scrape site protected by cloudfare

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

So I'm trying to scrape https://craft.co/tesla

When I visit from the browser, it opens correctly. However, when I use scrapy, it fetches the site but when I view the response,

```
view(response)
```

It shows the cloudfare site instead of the actual site.

Please how do I go about this??

Answer (score 4):

Cloudflare changes their techniques periodically and anyway you can just use a simple Python module to bypass Cloudflare's anti-bot page.
The module can be useful if you wish to scrape or crawl a website protected with Cloudflare. Cloudflare's anti-bot page currently just checks if the client supports Javascript, though they may add additional techniques in the future.

Due to Cloudflare continually changing and hardening their protection page, cloudscraper requires a JavaScript Engine/interpreter to solve Javascript challenges. This allows the script to easily impersonate a regular web browser without explicitly deobfuscating and parsing Cloudflare's Javascript.

Any script using cloudscraper will sleep for ~5 seconds for the first visit to any site with Cloudflare anti-bots enabled, though no delay will occur after the first request.

- [ https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cloudscraper/ ]

Please check this python module.

The simplest way to use cloudscraper is by calling create_scraper().

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()  # returns a CloudScraper instance
# Or: scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()  # CloudScraper inherits from requests.Session
print(scraper.get("http://somesite.com").text)  # => "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>..."
```

Any requests made from this session object to websites protected by Cloudflare anti-bot will be handled automatically. Websites not using Cloudflare will be treated normally. You don't need to configure or call anything further, and you can effectively treat all websites as if they're not protected with anything.

You use cloudscraper exactly the same way you use Requests. cloudScraper works identically to a Requests Session object, just instead of calling requests.get() or requests.post(), you call scraper.get() or scraper.post().

Comment: Thanks. This works for me.

Comment: Does not work as of 5/4/2022. I get the `Please Wait... | Cloudflare` HTML response page

Comment: Does not work for me also. Getting 403 error.

Comment: Does not work for me either, it says I do need a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Use `requests-HTML`. You can use this code to avoid block:

```py
# pip install requests-html
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'your url come here'
s = HTMLSession()
s.headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'
r = s.get(url)
r.html.render(timeout=8000)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: The solution works even to bypass errors `Detected a Cloudflare Captcha challenge version 2`, but if by blocking requests from a single ip is not helping